# Merge 2 Different List with order condition in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

So I want to join from 2 different list without any key and order that list some condition.

I have `Class` like this:

```
public class DataA
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class DataB
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

And the list like this:

```
var listDataA = new List<DataA> 
{ 
    new DataA { Data = "data a 1", Order = 1, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 12, 00, 00, 00) },
    new DataA { Data = "data a 2", Order = 2, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 13, 00, 00, 00) },
    new DataA { Data = "data a 5", Order = 5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 14, 16, 00, 00) },
    new DataA { Data = "data a 6", Order = 6, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 15, 00, 00, 00) },
    new DataA { Data = "data a 7", Order = 7, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 16, 00, 00, 00) }
};

var listDataB = new List<DataB> 
{
    new DataB { Data = "data b 5", Order = 5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 14, 14, 00, 00) },
    new DataB { Data = "data b 8", Order = 8, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 16, 00, 00, 00) }
};
```

I want to order the list from each other `Order` property, if the `Order` value is the same it will check the `CreatedOn` property. so the data will look like this:

```
[
    { Data = "data a 1", Order = 1, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 12, 00, 00, 00) },
    { Data = "data a 2", Order = 2, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 13, 00, 00, 00) },
    { Data = "data b 5", Order = 5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 14, 14, 00, 00) },
    { Data = "data a 5", Order = 5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 14, 16, 00, 00) },
    { Data = "data a 6", Order = 6, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 15, 00, 00, 00) },
    { Data = "data a 7", Order = 7, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 16, 00, 00, 00) },
    { Data = "data b 8", Order = 8, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2020, 11, 16, 00, 00, 00) }
]
```

How can I do this in Linq?

Comment: These are different types, there's not much support for handling this in one collection unless you have inheritance. Can you explain what the resulting list type would be of type?

Comment: If the two objects had been the same type you could've used `listDataA.Concat(listDataB).OrderBy(d => d.Order).ThenBy(d => d.CreatedOn)`

Comment: Do you need to preserve the fact that one is a DataA and the other is a DataB?

Comment: `DataA` and `DataB` has other property that not the same, my example class is just to simplify that

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, If possible I want to know which data is from class `DataA` and which from class `DataB`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really, i think you'd be better off defining an interface for these classes that mentions the common parts you want to use

```
interface IDataX
{
   int Order { get; set; }
   DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class DataA: IDataX ...

public class DataB: IDataX ...
```

Then you could do like

```
var output = listDataA.Cast<IDataX>().Concat(listDataB).OrderBy(d => d.Order).ThenBy(d => d.CreatedOn);
```

as Data is common to both, you could add that to the interface too, and then you could use Data from IDataX without having to know specifically whether the object underneath is a DataA or a DataB.

---

If you're against that (and also against a similar idea of having a parent class for A/B that has the common properties Order/Created..), you might have to project to some common holder (which could equally be anonymous but presented here as not for sake of example):

```
class Holder{
   public int Order { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

   public object OriginalData { get; set; }
}
```

And concat projections..

```
listA
  .Select(a => new Holder { Order = a.Order, CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn, OriginalData = a})
  .Concat(
     listB.Select(b => new Holder { Order = b.Order, CreatedOn = b.CreatedOn, OriginalData = b})
  ).OrderBy(x => x.Order).ThenBy(x => x.CreatedOn)
```

..then cast back the `OriginalData` when you want to use it.. (`if(x.OriginalData is DataA a) ... else if(x.OriginalData is DataB b)` which is a bit.. ugh)

Personally, I'd definitely be leveraging some kind of polymorphism for this

Comment: yeah I think the polymorphism one is much cleaner. But I have other problem, The previous developer use Anonymous Types and want to join it with other class. Is there any approach for this problem? If no I think, I'll just convert that Anonymous Types to some temporary classes.

Comment: Can you more accurately explain what you mean? if these classes A/B are AT then their type is essentially defined by the number and type of their properties, so if they differ, theyre different types, makes 'em a bit more of a nuisance to work with; you can still cast them to an IDataX if they have the necessary properties (I think then you'll have some ugly trickery to cast them back to a usable AT when you're done) - perhaps you can do all your work with the IDataX and the common superset of properties, but when you hit something like this it's prob an indicator of "time for a class/record"